# Is it possible to create a notification in the Windows tray, in a way other than using Windows forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

During my research, I found several options for implementing notifications, but most of them were related to Windows Forms. Among these options, NotifyIcon seems to be the most commonly used, which indicates that it's likely one of the most popular choices.

Additionally, I have already conducted a test with Electron using JavaScript.

Comment: Progressive Web Apps support [push notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Tutorials/js13kGames/Re-engageable_Notifications_Push). If you're using a framework like angular you can simply run `ng add @angular/pwa` and inject `SwPush` [tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/). Other frameworks will surely provide libraries too

Comment: @Pieterjan That's probably not what OP is after. As I read the question this is more about creating a tray-icon for interacting with an app.

Comment: Do you want a tray icon next to the clock, or a Toast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview if the former you could just copy the source code https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NotifyIcon.cs,e45ff5ceb4b9d9ac